# Page not found(404)

Tags: python, django, django-views

Am doing this simple company appraisal application that probably has detail views. whereas the list view displays normally, whenever i click to view it's details, i get the page not found (404) error. It works in that if you are to click on a department (list view), it had to take you to a detail page which shows the logo, and posts under that department.

traceback;

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/1//
Using the URLconf defined in Employee.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
^appraisal/
^ ^$ [name='index']
^ ^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$ [name='detail']
^static\/(?P<path>.*)$
^media\/(?P<path>.*)$
The current URL, 1//, didn't match any of these.
```

my views;

```
from django.views import generic
from .models import Department

class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = "index.html"
    context_object_name = "departments"

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Department.objects.all()


class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Department
    template_name = "detail.html"
```

my urls;

project/urls

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^appraisal/', include('Appraisal.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('Appraisal.urls')),
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

app/urls;

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = 'Appraisal'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
]
```

my models;

```
class Department(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    Leader = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
    Department_logo = models.FileField()
    is_favorite = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.Name)


class Post(models.Model):
    Title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    Department = models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_favorite = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.Title)
```

somebody help me solve this, i know it's really a small thing that has gotten this not working.
thanks!!

Comment: You have two slashes at the end of the URL you're trying to go to; that won't match the pattern. We can't tell how they got there without seeing the template that includes the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your link is buggy `http://127.0.0.1:8000/1//` one slash too many at the end

it should be either `http://127.0.0.1:8000/1/` or `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` for urls to match correctly

you probably have wrong link building in template.